# Twitter API 1.1 - render twitter's t.co links

Tags: twitter, hyperlink

I want to display the tweets of an account in my website. The problem is that the tweets appear always with the format `http://t.co/...`, instead of the full link as desired by me.

For instance, I obtain:

```
the rules of the game are all implemented - local players can play together in this link: http://t.co/Nf7j4TaB

if you are very curious... then, here is the link to the xodul's section under development: http://t.co/6Zbti36T

etc...
```

and I want that these tweets appear like this:

```
the rules of the game are all implemented - local players can play together in this link: http://xodul.com/tests/js/

if you are very curious... then, here is the link to the xodul's section under development: http://xodul.com/tests 

etc...
```

To make my application I've followed the instructions from:

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1) (from here we can get the text of each tweet, with the links coming in the format: `http://t.co/...`)

[Rendering links in tweet when using Get Statuses API 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610968/rendering-links-in-tweet-when-using-get-statuses-api-1-1/15633797#15633797) (the code of the highest scored answer, in this link replaces, for instance, the text `"http://t.co/Nf7j4TaB"` with the hyperlink `"<a target='_blank' href='http://t.co/Nf7j4TaB'>http://t.co/Nf7j4TaB</a>"`)

I appreciate very much any help on how to render the twitter's links!

Comment: The code of the non-accepted answer is much easier to use ;) Regardless, maybe [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) can help. It's about tweet entities.

Comment: OK, maybe, I've just followed Rivers' answer (the accepted one at june 14th) because it's shorter than the other, which is now the accepted one...

Comment: That's because accepted one explains how to make the application and get your keys. If you use River's example, you can't @ tweet people correctly and there are loads of other issues that have been fixed. Feel free to use that if you like. The shortest solution isn't always the best. Lazy! :p

Comment: @jimbo I've removed the reference to the particular answer of the other page, so anyone can choose which answer wants to follow. I've only followed and then cited a code that worked for my case, and I didn't noticed the other code. I don't see why my messages have deserved -1, I'm not lazy.

Comment: Not my -1, but the latest accepted answer is most likely to be the most useful / correct :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers.

After analyzing the JSON in the suggested link (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities), I wrote a solution to the exposed problem:

```
// ...
$twitter_data = json_decode($json);    // last line of the code in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539


// print the tweets, with the full URLs:
foreach ($twitter_data as $item) {
    $text = $item->text;

    foreach ($item->entities->urls as $url) {
        $text = str_replace($url->url, $url->expanded_url, $text);
    }
    echo $text . '<br /><br />';

    // optionally, here, the code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610968/
    // can be added, too.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the tutorial you followed you can use these attributes to show actual link.

```
Note: In API v1.1, entities will always be included unless you set include_entities to False or 0.

The urls entity

An array of URLs extracted from the Tweet text. Each URL entity comes with the following attributes:

url:    The URL that was extracted
display_url:    (only for t.co links) Not a URL but a string to display instead of the URL
expanded_url:   (only for t.co links) The fully resolved URL
indices:    The character positions the URL was extracted from
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only solution for now to get Twitter posts on your site without using new 1.1 API and actually returns the full url in posts, not the twitter shortened version :-) http://goo.gl/JinwJ

Comment: Did you really have to use a shortened link in an answer about how to avoid shortened links?